# Error trying to proxy url in solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am facing an issue while selecting from solrcloud Node , can you let me know the reason and resolution for the same

NOTE: I have create a custom authentication and authorization plugin , This works fine when SSL is not enabled. This occurs when ssl is enabled along with external zookeeper

I am using solr-6.2.1 , and have setup an external zookeeper, I have 2 solr nodes instances at ports 8983 and 7574( same isse occurs qith single node too)

When I execute the command-:

```
curl -E solr-ssl.pem:tcserver --cacert /home/was/root.pem -H 'API-KEY:trial:value' -X POST 'https://slvboxname.company.com:8983/solr/dev2/select?indent=on&q=:&wt=json'
```

Please find below error-:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 {metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException},msg=Error trying to proxy request for url: http://10.211.21.160:8983/solr/dev2/select,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error trying to proxy request for url: http://10.901.21.900:8983/solr/dev2/select
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.remoteQuery(HttpSolrCall.java:588)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:443)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 10.901.21.900:8983 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.remoteQuery(HttpSolrCall.java:560)
    ... 30 more
,code=500}</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/dev2/select. Reason:
<pre>    {metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException},msg=Error trying to proxy request for url: http://10.211.21.160:8983/solr/dev2/select,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error trying to proxy request for url: http://:10.901.21.9008983/solr/dev2/select
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.remoteQuery(HttpSolrCall.java:588)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:443)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 10.901.21.9008983 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.remoteQuery(HttpSolrCall.java:560)
    ... 30 more
,code=500}</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to query ?

Comment: dev2 is a collection i have created, I am running a simple select all query. I tried the same without https and external zookeeper and it works

Comment: also I have created a custom authentication and authorization solr plugin it gets called in above scenario and the above error occurs after the plugin gets executed

Comment: `q=: ` ? change to q=*:*

Comment: Execute this command:
    curl -E solr-ssl.pem:tcserver --cacert /home/was/root.pem -H 'API-KEY:trial:value' -X POST 'https://slvboxname.company.com:8983/solr/dev2/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json'